# Create a gui in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to create a gui in matlab with a push button and a panel.

**Requirements**: Upon clicking the button the dialogue must open to choose a file and after selecting image from this dialogue the image must be shown to that panel of gui.

How do I do this?

How to show the image on the gui panel?

My current status so far:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = ...
uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.jpeg';'*.bmp';'*.*'},'File Selector');
set(handles.axes2, 'Visible','on'); 
imshow(IMG,'Parent',TheAxisHandleToDrawOn)
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('Image upload Canceled')
end
```

I tried this but it's not working, how to do this?

Comment: % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     [filename, pathname] = ...
     uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.jpeg';'*.bmp';'*.*'},'File Selector');
     set(handles.panel1, 'Visible','on');
     complete = strcat(pathname,filename);
set(handles.panel1,'string',complete);
I = dicomread(complete);
imshow(I,[]);
guidata(hObject, handles);
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('Image upload Canceled')        
end
 i also tried this but it's also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to your `callback` you have first to `read` the selected image by using `imread`; you can use `fullfile` to build the complete filename.

Then you use the matrix returned by `imread` as input for the `imshow` function.

**Edit following the comments**

In order to show the image within a `uipanel` you have to add an `axes` in the panel and use it as `parent` in the call to `imshow`.

If the image you want to display is not in the current folder or in a folder on the MATLAB path, you have to specify the full path name (ref. [imread](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#btnczv9-3)).

In the following you can find the `.m` file of the GUI I've build for test.

The GUI contains:

- an `axes` (tag: axes2)
- a `uipanel` (tag: uipanel1)
- an `axes` (tag: axes_up) embedded in the `uipanel`
- two `radiobuttons` (tag: radiobutton1 and radiobutton2) to select the axes on which to show the image
- two `statictext` fields (tag: text2 and text3) to show the filename of the selected images
- a `pushbutton` (tag: pushbutton1) to select the image to be displayed
- a `pushbutton` (tag: pushbutton3) to run the [imcontrast](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontrast.html) tool in case of selection of a [.dcm](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html) image

The code has been tested on R2012b and 2015b.

```
function varargout = disp_fig(varargin)
% DISP_FIG MATLAB code for disp_fig.fig
%      DISP_FIG, by itself, creates a new DISP_FIG or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = DISP_FIG returns the handle to a new DISP_FIG or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      DISP_FIG('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in DISP_FIG.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      DISP_FIG('Property','Value',...) creates a new DISP_FIG or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before disp_fig_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to disp_fig_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help disp_fig

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 25-Apr-2016 14:18:18

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @disp_fig_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @disp_fig_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before disp_fig is made visible.
function disp_fig_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to disp_fig (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for disp_fig
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes disp_fig wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = disp_fig_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Select the image to be displayed
[filename, pathname] = ...
uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.jpeg';'*.bmp';'*.*'},'File Selector');
% Build the full filename
img_file=fullfile(pathname,filename)
% Split the filename to get its extension
[the_path,the_name,the_ext]=fileparts(img_file);
% Set the current StaticText uicontrol based on the selected RadioButton
curr_txt=handles.text2;
if(get(handles.radiobutton2,'value'))
   curr_txt=handles.text3;
end
% Check for image valid selection
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('Image upload Canceled')
   set(curr_txt,'string','Image upload Canceled')
else
   % If an image has been selected
   set(curr_txt,'string',img_file)
   % If the image is a ".dcm"
   if(strcmp(the_ext,'.dcm'))
      % Read it with dicomread and enable the pushbutton to run the
      % IMCONTRAST tool
      IMG=dicomread(img_file);
      set(handles.pushbutton3,'visible','on')
   else
      % If the image is a ".jpg", ".bmp", ...
      % Read it with imread and disable the pushbutton to run the
      % IMCONTRAST tool
      IMG=imread(img_file);
      set(handles.pushbutton3,'visible','off')
   end
   % Identify the axes on which to display the image according to the
   % selected radiobutton
   if(get(handles.radiobutton1,'value'))
      the_parent=handles.axes2;
      set(handles.axes2, 'Visible','on'); 
   else
      the_parent=handles.axes_up;
   end
   % Showthe image
   imshow(IMG,'Parent',the_parent)
end


% --- Executes on button press in radiobutton1.
function radiobutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of radiobutton1

% If the first radiobutton has been selected, disable the second onre
r1=get(handles.radiobutton1,'value');
if(r1)
   set(handles.radiobutton2,'value',0);
end

% --- Executes on button press in radiobutton2.
function radiobutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to radiobutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of radiobutton2

% If the second radiobutton has been selected, disable the first one
r2=get(handles.radiobutton2,'value');
if(r2)
   set(handles.radiobutton1,'value',0);
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Run the IMCONTRAST tool to the proper axes according to the selected
% radiobutton
r1=get(handles.radiobutton1,'value');
if(r1)
   imcontrast(handles.axes2)
else
   imcontrast(handles.axes_up)
end
```

**Structure of the GUI**

[image]

**The GUI ... working**

[image]

To test the `.dcm` image display I've used, as examples, the images from [DICOM sample image sets](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/).

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: sir thanx for your answer  what if i use uipanel1 instead of axes2?                                                                                              function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = ...
uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.jpeg';'*.bmp';'*.*'},'File Selector');
img_file=fullfile(pathname,filename);
if isequal(filename,0)
   disp('Image upload Canceled')
else
   set(handles.uipanel1, 'Visible','on'); 
   % Read the image
   IMG=imread(img_file);
   % Show the image on the axes
   imshow(IMG,'Parent',handles.uipanel1)
end

Comment: i tried this code but it's showing following error message ??? Error using ==> imshow>validateParent at 312
HAX must be a valid axes handle.

Error in ==> imshow at 221
      validateParent(specific_args.Parent)

Error in ==> untitled>pushbutton1_Callback at 93
   imshow(IMG,'Parent',handles.uipanel1)

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> untitled at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: sir i tried code that u have given to me in which there was axes2 but its showing img_file =

C:\Users\UJWAL\Downloads\ZjSqKcW.jpg on command window but not displaying image in axes2 which i have created on gui

Comment: Sorry for this late answer. I've updated the answer (and the code). To briefly answer to you comments: if you want to show the image within a uipanel you have to add an axes in the panel and use it as parent in the call to imshow. `imread` accepts as `filename` input a "fufull path name" in case he image is not in the current folder or in a folder on the MATLAB path so I do not why you can not get the image displayed. To test my GUI I've used images stored in a folder not in the MatLab path (ref. to the textboxes in the `.gif`).

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it to let the community know you no longer need help.

Comment: Happy I've been of use to you, you can accept the amswer by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is the final solution for the problem
```

function browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to browse (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname]=uigetfile( {'*.jpg';'*.gif';'*.png';'*.bmp'},'Select file'); 
 MyImage = strcat(pathname, filename);
%This code checks if the user pressed cancel on the dialog.
        if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
            uiwait(msgbox ('User pressed cancel','failed','modal')  )
            hold on;
        else
            uiwait(msgbox('User selected image sucessfully','sucess','modal'));
            hold off;
             imshow(MyImage,'Parent',handles.axes1);
        end
        global Imagevariable;
        Imagevariable=MyImage;
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);